# E: The package python3-apt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04, server

[every time I got this error when I run any command. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

E: The package python3-apt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  *You have tagged 12.04 & 14.04?*  python3-apt is in default repos for 16.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-apt) so I would check sources.list* file(s), internet connection, but of course `sudo apt-get update` first.  Also please copy & paste text into your question, not provide an image of text.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Please try to reinstall this package from repository:
`apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt`.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Run this command with sudo.
Could you give us an answers for @guiverc questions from comment on your question?

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease               
Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-apt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
karan@karan:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-apt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Which of repository do you have enabled on this system? If the result you put is all from "apt-get install" command I think you have disabled the standard ubuntu repository on your system. The configuration of repository you could find in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Comment: how could i resolve

Comment: Enabling the standard ubuntu repository. Show me the content of your sources.list file